# Plotting data lines properly annotated with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, automation, chemistry, annotations

I am plotting a series of rather busy plots consisting of many (5..25) lines of experimental data using `pgfplots 1.14` and `TikZ 3.0.1a`. These curves are often overlapping, coexist near `x` or `y` axis, and generally have non-uniform appearance. I want to annotate each curve once, so currently the following piece of code for nodes is used:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage{english}
  \setotherlanguage{german}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{
    decorations.markings}
  \tikzset{>=latex}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
  xlabel     = {pH},
  ylabel     = {\ch{V^V}, \%},
  axis lines = left,
  clip       = false,
  xmin = 0.5, xmax = 14,
  ymin = 0,   ymax = 105,
  xtick      = {1,2,...,13},
  ytick      = {0,10,...,100},
  width      = \textwidth,
  height     = 12cm,
  grid       = major,
  grid style = {dashed,gray!30},
]

\addplot [smooth,thick] table [x = pH, y = {[VO2]+}, col sep = comma] {plots/distr-V-O-01.csv} 
node[pos = 0.2, pin = {90:\ch{[VO2]^+}}, inner sep = 0pt]{};

\addplot [smooth,thick] table [x = pH, y = {[H3V10O28]3-}, col sep = comma] {plots/distr-V-O-01.csv} 
node[pos = 0.5, pin = {-90:\ch{[H3V10O28]^{3-}}}, inner sep = 0pt]{};

\addplot [smooth,thick] table [x = pH, y = {[H2V10O28]4-}, col sep = comma] {plots/distr-V-O-01.csv} 
node[pos = 0.7, pin = {120:\ch{[H2V10O28]^{4-}}}, inner sep = 0pt]{};

%%% And so on for each data series, there are about 25 entries on average

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

where `\ch{A3B5O_x}` is one of the chemical formulas corresponding to the data series. Figuring out the correct angle and node position every time (so that labels, lines and axis are not overlapping) is extremely tedious, and to me it seems there must be an easier way of labeling such data plots automatically, so that 3 parameters - pin length, pin angle and node position on the line - are correctly estimated automatically based on how occupied certain plot area is.

And yes, I really need pins, using `nodes near coords` or summarizing all data lines in a legend area clutter plots inevitably.

If you could suggest another tool for this job beyond `pgfplots`, which is XeLaTeX-friendly, please feel free to do so.

I'm not sure how to attach .csv file properly, so here are the first lines from data file:

```
pH,[VO2]+,[H3V10O28]3-,[H2V10O28]4-,[HV10O28]5-,[V10O28]6-,[V4O12]4-,[H2VO4]-,[H2V2O7]2-,[V6O18]6-,[V5O15]5-,[V3O10]5-,[V4O13]6-,[HV4O13]5-,[HV2O7]3-,[HVO4]2-,[V2O7]4-,[VO4]3-
1,,0.021,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,,,0.122,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.0099,99.62,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.0929,93.542,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.1033,,,3.605,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.1295,,3.035,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.1328,90.377,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.1677,,,6.389,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.1991,86.072,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.2,,,,0.027,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.252,82.906,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.271,,,9.994,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.2755,80.311,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.3187,77.082,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.3353,,,13.157,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.3558,,9.676,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.3586,73.916,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.3739,,,15.309,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.3985,70.751,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

There are about 1000 lines. [image: Here is a cropped area of the approximate plot]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A minimal example of code seems necessary to better understand the problem.

Comment: I guess this should do it, I added MWE to the main question.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. Your MWE is still not compilable, because you didn't provide some data file, so we still don't have an idea how it looks like. (And your MWE starts with `\begin{document}` rather than `\documentclass{...}`.)

Comment: You don't have to share the *whole* data file if you don't want to, but at least for the few lines you added to the MWE it would be nice. Maybe also of help would be a screenshot of your current plot including *all* data rows so we have an impression of your real/full problem.

Comment: My bad, I screwed MWE indeed, sorry for that. But again, the problem is not how data is plotted, I'm looking for the automated way of arranging annotations on a 2D line plot, e.g. without tweaking the position of each given label.

Comment: As far as I know there is no automated way to do it which takes care of that the label isn't overlapping something else.

Comment: But if you have 25 lines, all of them showing in the same style which overlap multiple times that is -- in my point of few -- a very bad visualization anyway.  Good luck with this attempt.

Comment: That's why I'd like to use pinned annotations, aligned properly the plot looks decent enough. But the effort is not worth it unless the process is automated, cause as I said, too many lines and too many plots to be taken care of manually. But thanks anyway, at least I can broaden my search now. I have much less experience with gnuplot and matplotlib, but I assume these tools are also cannot do what intended here?

Comment: One very minor unrelated comment: `pgfplots` is a separate package from `pgf`/TikZ, although it builds on that. It is TikZ that has 3.0.1a as the latest stable version, `pgfplots` has 1.14.

Comment: True, I was confused by the output of `\pgfversion` command and mistakenly assigned it to the version of `pgfplots`. With `\listfiles` I confirm the correct version of `pgfplots` logged  is indeed 1.14 of 2016/08/10.

Comment: why you not use legend for your plot? it is intended for such plots ...

Comment: why not put the formulas directly in the nodes instead of pins? Then you would only need `pos` key and the angle would be adjusted automatically.

Comment: @Zarco I would doubt a legend is something of a use in here. How you would visually link around 20+ different sequences plotted in B&W on a vastly different and mostly random scale? Not to mention that such legend is going to need a lot of space somewhere on the precious x - y area (which you also have to figure out manually for each plot, I guess), which is already a mess; plus there is no real estate aside, literally, as this will compress the plot beyond recognition.

Comment: @percusse I use pins to avoid text labels overlapping with the lines, x-axis and other labels.

Comment: You can place nodes as arbitrarily as pins though. I don't see the actual benefit of pins that woudn't be possible with nodes